# Binding values to panel title

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a problem when I am binding values to a panel title.

My code basically looks like this :

```
Ext.define('serviceteamWorkflow.view.core.ServiceteamWorkflow', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    bind: {
        title: 'First Name : {firstName} Last Name : {lastName}'
    },

})
```

The problem is that nothing shows in the title when one of the bound values is null or undefined. Ie. If one of the bound values is invalid then the whole thing won't show.

I would like to just show nothing if the bound value is invalid. ie :

**First Name : Last Name : Doe**

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Default the firstName/lastName values in the viewmodel data to empty string.

Comment: could you also solve this using formulas?

Comment: I guess, but it's easier to provide a default.

Comment: thanks! It works. Can you add as a proper answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a formula that would reference your bindings in your view model:

```
Ext.define('serviceteamWorkflow.view.core.ServiceteamWorkflow', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
bind: {
    title: {showTitle}
},
```

})

Then inside your ServiceteamWorkflow view model:

```
    requires: [
    'Ext.app.bind.Formula'
],

data: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: 'Johnson'
},

formulas: {
    showTitle: function(get) {
        var firstName = get('firstName'),
            lastName  = get('lastName');

        return "First Name : " + firstName + " Last Name: " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as binding the title like in the OP. The `get()` calls create dependencies in the same fashion.

Comment: Yes but this will show the entire string in showTitle minus the missing first name

Comment: So will adding default empty values.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are like me wondering how to set default values to viewmodel as suggested by Evan Trimboli in the first comment, it should be set in a view:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    }
}
```

If you set your data somewhere dynamically, for example:

```
this.getViewModel().set('fullName', data);
```

you need to set defaults like this:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        fullName: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        }
    }
}
```